Joing two table producing eratic result
I am trying fetch records by join two table in MySQL but result is what I want.There are only two record in main table  but the query result producing multiple record( repeated) what is wrong in my query kindly help
My main table content is 
Produced output is 
SELECT 
  t1.txnid, 
  t1.stationeryissueddate, 
  t1.orderdate, 
  t1.purpose as pur1, 
  t1.status, 
  t1.stationerytype, 
  t1.stationeryqtyrqst, 
  t1.stationeryqtyissued, 
  t1.remark, 
  t2.purpose as pur2 
from 
  tblstationerystock t1 
  join tblstationerytype t2 on t1.purpose = t2.purpose 
where 
  t1.uin = 13218 
order by 
  t1.status desc


Welcome to SQL ;) This looks very much like you have selected the wrong column to join on, can you please edit the post to include the schema of tblstationarytype. An example dataset for both tables and your expected outcome would help too, then we can fully explore other options instead of suggesting hypothetical solutions.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.


For these types of queries, it is better to post with what your expected outcome is and to explain your logic.

Duplicate results is a common side effect of using a join incorrectly or not applying an adequate filter.

without a raw dataset or schema, it is hard to be more specific

We can break this down a bit though, when using a JOIN you are asking for the Cartesian Product of the two tables with a specific filter applied.
from 
  tblstationerystock t1 
  join tblstationerytype t2 on t1.purpose = t2.purpose

This is saying, "For each record in t1, get all of the records in t2 that have the same value of purpose and include those records in the result set."
This type of join is commonly used when t2 represents a lookup table and the match column, in this case purpose is unique, in that scenario no additional records will be added to the result because the lookup will only match a single row.

Usually the join criteria would use an identifier or type field in the t2. Your table names suggest that t2 holds type definitions that are referred to from the stock/item
So try to edit your join in the query similar to this:
from 
  tblstationerystock t1 
  join tblstationerytype t2 on t1.stationerytype = t2.tblstationerytype



